# Python calculate large number wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7

Recently I tried calculating Catalan number using Python!
I tried 2 ways to calculate Catalan number:

```
dp = np.zeros(160)
dp[0] = 1
for i in range(1, 100):
    for j in range(i):
        dp[i] += dp[j] * dp[i - j - 1]
```

and

```
n = int(raw_input())
catalan_n = int(math.factorial(n * 2) / math.factorial(n) / math.factorial(n + 1))
```

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) these should yield the same answer, but in my computer, when n equals about 31 or more, they give different results.

For example, given `n = 31`, the first implementation yield

```
14544636039226908
```

when the second

```
14544636039226909
```

The difference becomes larger when n is larger.

So, what is the reason? and how can I handle so that both implementations give the same ( and right ) result?

Comment: Which is the correct answer? First or second?

Comment: `math.factorial` converts to and from floating point, so whenever the result is slightly less than a whole number (which is permitted!), a small error gets introduced. And those add up.

Comment: the second one is correct

Comment: I highly recommend reading about how the floating point numbers are represented internally, it will be interesting as well as helpful.

Comment: @RobFoley OP says factorial version gives correct answer

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't have guessed that at all.

Comment: if you use arbitrary precision integers of python, they both produce the same result. however the one using `math.factorial` is way faster than the other. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `numpy`, avoid floating point, just ask Python to work with its native integers:

```
dp = [0] * 160
dp[0] = 1
for i in range(1, 100):
    for j in range(i):
        dp[i] += dp[j] * dp[i - j - 1]
```

You obtain the required result:

```
>>> dp[31]
14544636039226909
```

Comment: Same effect as changing the numpy array to have an integer (int64) type: `dp = np.zeros(32, dtype=np.int64)` (must also reduce the range of `i` to avoid an overflow at larger values of n)

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Be careful, there is a difference between 64bit integers in your example, and Python's unlimited integers. Python evaluates `1 << 100` to `1267650600228229401496703205376`, which is a value that cannot be represented by a 64bit integer.

Comment: This method is very slow compared to the one using `math.factorial`. See my answer.

Comment: @mescalinum I confirm that your solution is much faster. And it can be even faster if you change the second division to multiplication: `math.factorial(n * 2) // (math.factorial(n) * math.factorial(n + 1))`. And it can be even faster if the factorial of `n` is not calculated twice. Anyway, my main intention was to show that `numpy` is completely useless for this type of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Use integer division (`/` in Python 2.x; `//` in Python 3.x; see [PEP-0238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)).

Python can handle arbitrary length integers if you use integer arithmetic.

I tested this in Python 3.4:

```
>>> n = 31
>>> math.factorial(n * 2) // math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n + 1)
14544636039226909
```

more:

```
>>> n = 300
>>> math.factorial(n * 2) // math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n + 1)
448863594671741755862042783981742625904431712455792292112842929523169934910317996551330498997589600726489482164006103817421596314821101
633539230654646302151568026806610883615856
```

really up to any length:

```
>>> n = 3000
>>> math.factorial(n * 2) // math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n + 1)
519462652919542881721365123011179975310102937604940266719385892606880110765316718891395071497514229126429925976055679251223128074749037
835401036449153787085998615080079472024510673995437465556202913988662201476481724554419588352460788248600870845757882846138810676725538
563107883030181266599172195406194674262178494218158106628185084640318133660880669410879631422165901582338980573378926964500556169385404
736100270128669761789892432503454091737948987203916800528049625631943853069946630768308689117691085645832918187925556506072761147675438
429882843604702193420613753732662694259398583327509305925877958076192508779774600671550059625449220766972323426048569573870742646138682
330665271970741737026351041002094725570021658043868050133870464978010862336227347394228402203592519509440711956260056901367528427111161
296369965071015622062369906953928825160542499316029260848901981705520546040735573456838161278143205046287274001985209051501791057064860
777924614712880895844889661062906810651227996795699200705689167041491295132678905362506739442596941049468768934515387686685216725429630
569388433843181310525905915079353425197760576036382793301451923253554632457764696533239230792374371551049829770586784317601794822668699
762524880276131689250405042237665587324829345738473826128110671929192283799781962486065016982222602138402014572024398921586637930463872
133232259555872008143437104541075975585105539708870387267774173630656199269799668692949281254988538412342931876350743005256155083395855
293674222742887729441736406441460871100319788599494948199980318713167545334283812660431840713561226653525108082181718879207846399491603
046897066186692086000900551598963656721594748873629207464689206076706897152859647808013130407215834207952366890322422542440601278699142
2249907274578524259056058561900439043252745600
```

The implementation using `math.factorial` is also orders of magnitude faster than the iterative version:

```
p1='''
dp = [1] + [0] * n;
for i in range(1,1+n):
    for j in range(i):
        dp[i] += dp[j] * dp[i - j - 1]
'''
p2='''
math.factorial(n * 2) // math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n + 1)
'''

# benchmarks:

import timeit

>>> timeit.timeit(p1, 'n=300', number=1000)
14.639895505999448

>>> timeit.timeit(p2, 'import math; n=300', number=1000)
0.06054379299166612

>>> timeit.timeit(p1, 'n=3000', number=10)
207.88161920005223

>>> timeit.timeit(p2, 'import math; n=3000', number=10)
0.042887639498803765
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `numpy.zeros` uses `float` as the default element data type. You do not show how you retrieve the resulting number in the first version, but I am supposing that you cast it to `int`, otherwise, you would see the result as `1.45446360392e+16` or something similar:

```py
def your_version(n):
    dp = np.zeros(n + 1)
    dp[0] = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(i):
            dp[i] += dp[j] * dp[i - j - 1]
    return int(dp[n])
```

The rounding errors are removed if you specify that you want to work with integers in Numpy: use `np.zeros(n + 1, dtype=np.uint64)` and the result is correct.

By the way, @dlask is right to recommend you avoid Numpy. You can find memoized versions of the same formulas [on Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Catalan_numbers#Python), and they are all faster than the Numpy version:

```
# The recurrent formula, memoized
In [9]: %timeit catalan.catalan(31)
The slowest run took 7.65 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 249 ns per loop

# The factorial formula, memoized
In [10]: %timeit catalan.cat_direct(31)
The slowest run took 10.21 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 µs per loop

# The recurrent formula with Numpy
In [11]: %timeit catalan.your_version(31)
1000 loops, best of 3: 259 µs per loop

# The factorial version without memoization
In [12]: %timeit catalan.your_other_version(31)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.98 µs per loop
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure it's just a division problem the same way that 5/2 will give you 2.
Also changing it to float won't fix it as floats only save a few (10 maybe? I don't remember) digits.

You could try first calculating the entire top part and then the entire bottom part and then divide them. By doing that you could also check for problems with %, I don't remember exactly how Catalan numbers work but it should fix it for you.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Please see the comments.